# Binding AJAX data to html list template

Tags: javascript, data-binding, jquery

I'd like a functionality such as binding that is in silverlight, but this works for html and ajax calls.

I retrieve an array of the following objects from the server which is the user information whose class looks like the following:

```
public class User{
    public int UserId;
    public string ImgUrl;
    public string UserName;
}
```

If I have a List Item Template like the following:

```
<div id="{USERID}">
    <img src="{ITEM_IMAGE_URL}" />
    <span>UserName: </span><span>{USERNAME}</span>
</div>
```

Is there a way in javascript/Jquery do easily bind the data to this item template?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [parseTemplate](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/05/03/using-jquery-with-client-side-data-binding-templates.aspx) Jquery extension walk through. It also has a fully functional project you can download and run. The sample works great.

```
  var output = $('#MyTemplate').parseTemplate(json);
                        $('#MyTemplateOutput').html(output);
```

It uses this syntax for the templates.

```
<td id="CustomerRow_<#= i.toString() #>">
 <#= cust.FirstName #>
</td>
```